# How to apply sequence order in trigger?

Tags: triggers, informix

In Informix, I need to update 2 (two) tables when the trigger is executed. Let's say Table_A and Table_B. In Table_A, there is a int8 (long data type) column as primary key. When a new record is inserted, this primary key column will retrieve the value from a sequence. This is the code:

```
sequence_A.nextVal
```

In Table_B, there is a foreign key column that references the primary key in Table_A. In order to make the primary key and the foreign key tally, I use `sequence_A.currVal` to insert the value into this foreign key column.

I did try the code below but Informix give me syntax error.

```
create trigger The_Trigger
insert on The_Table referencing new as n
for each row
(
  insert into Table_A(...) value(sequence_A.nextVal, ...)

  insert into Table_B(...) value(sequence_A.currVal, ...)
)
```

If I separate the insert statement into 2 (two) difference triggers, it works. Thus I was thinking to create 2 (two) triggers on The_Table. Let's say Trigger_A and Trigger_B, may I know how can I ensure that Trigger_A will get execute first then only Thrigger_B. Can I specify the order execution on triggers? Can this be done? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt, you omitted the comma between the two INSERT statements, and the keyword is VALUES, not VALUE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER The_Trigger
INSERT ON The_Table REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW
(
    INSERT INTO Table_A(...) VALUES(sequence_A.nextVal, ...),
    INSERT INTO Table_B(...) VALUES(sequence_A.currVal, ...)
)
```

With those two changes, I believe you would have sequential execution.

Given a sufficiently recent version of Informix, you can have multiple triggers for a single event on a single table.  The sequence of execution is the sequence in which the triggers are defined.